# Verificar se existe valor dupliado no while

Tags: php

Estou a meio dia tentando fazer isso.

Tenho esse loop

```
if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_es_1_aux) == 1){
   echo "";
}else{
   $sql_es_1 = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT peso FROM tb_sub_agrupamento 
                                      WHERE id_ctr IN ($id_ctr_ok) AND 
                                       peso <> ''") or die(mysqli_error($config));


  if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_es_1) <= '0'){
    echo "";
  }else{

       while($r_sql_es_1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_es_1)){

           $peso_sel_es1 = $r_sql_es_1[0];                                                  
        }
    }
}
```

$peso_sel_es1 pode vir repetido.

Existe alguma forma de verificar se está repetido fora do while?

Se eu transformar ela em array (colocando []) ajuda?

Preciso determinar que, se for repetido, não mostre o peso.

Comment: Você quer exibir o valor repetido apenas uma única vez certo?

Comment: Não exatamente. Preciso verificar somente se existe ou não repetido. Depois de verificar, será um if simples. Se tiver repetido não mostra o bloco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode resolver na sua consulta agrupando os pesos. E contando quantos do mesmo existem. Ai no PHP você compara se a repetição é maior que 1.

```
SELECT 
    peso, 
    COUNT(peso) AS repeticoes 
FROM 
    tb_sub_agrupamento 
WHERE 
    id_ctr IN ($id_ctr_ok) 
    AND 
    peso <> '' 
GROUP BY 
    peso
```

Ou se você não quiser mostrar os pesos repetidos, somente os que forem únicos. A consulta assim também resolve. Não tendo necessidade de regra de negócio no fonte.

```
SELECT 
    peso, 
    COUNT(peso) AS repeticoes 
FROM 
    tb_sub_agrupamento 
WHERE 
    id_ctr IN ($id_ctr_ok) 
    AND 
    peso <> '' 
GROUP BY 
    peso
HAVING
    repeticoes = 1
```